# Stripe error "No such payment_intent: pi_1GS0redacted" when using newly created account

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a (test) Stripe integration working with an account I created years ago.

I made a new account (with the same login).

When I used the new account, I was first required (by an error) to add a `payment_method_types: ['card']` which I had not previously needed.

It still failed, now with an error:

```
No such payment_intent: pi_1GS0redacted
```

`pi_1GS0redacted` appears on my dashboard as "incomplete".

I have changed the secret key in my code (to match the new account).  The new one begins "sk_test_", the old one was just random letters.

Is there an API difference between an account created years ago, and one created a few days ago, which now requires use of `payment_method_types`?

I'm using code from: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment "2 Create a PaymentIntent Server-side" which does not specify `payment_method_types`.

How can I get my new account to work?

Comment: Almost certainly this is an API key mismatch, and you're looking for an object that doesn't exist in the Stripe Account of the API key you're using here.

Comment: You are right.  I had changed the private key used in the NodeJS backend, but had forgotten to change the public key in client.js.  If you turn your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"No such"` errors on Stripe for otherwise-valid IDs are almost certainly an API key mismatch; you're looking for an object that doesn't exist in the Stripe Account of the API key you're using here.

It can also sometimes be a missing (or present where it shouldn't be) [`Stripe-Account` header](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#stripe-account-header) if you're using Connect.